# Do virtual functions have to be public?

Tags: c++

Here is the way I have my base class working:

```
class AguiWidgetBase
{
    //variables
    AguiDockingEnum dockingStyle;
    std::string text;
    AguiRectangle clientRectangle;
    AguiColor tintColor;
    AguiColor fontColor;
    std::map<int,int,CmpIntInt> children;

    //private methods
    void zeroMemory();
    virtual void onPaint();
    virtual void onAddChildControl(AguiWidgetBase *control);
    virtual void onTintColorChanged(AguiColor color);
    virtual void onDockingStyleChanged(AguiDockingEnum style);
    virtual void onTextChanged(std::string text);
    virtual void onThemeChanged(const AguiTheme &theme);
    void (*onPaintCallback)(AguiRectangle clientRect);
    void (*onTintColorChangedCallback)();
    void (*onDockingStyleChangedCallback)();
    void (*onTextChangedCallback)();
    void (*onThemeChangedCallback)();

protected:
    AguiWidgetBase *parentWidget;
public:
    AguiWidgetBase(void);
    ~AguiWidgetBase(void);

    void addChildControl(AguiWidgetBase *control);
    void removeChildControl(AguiWidgetBase *control);
    AguiWidgetBase* getParent();
    void paint();
    void setTintColor(AguiColor color);
    AguiColor getTintColor();
    void setDockingStyle(AguiDockingEnum style);
    AguiDockingEnum getDockingStyle();
    void setText(std::string text);
    std::string getText();
    void SetTheme( const AguiTheme &theme);
};
```

Some of them work like this. There is a regular non-overridable funcion which calls the virtual function and the function pointer if its not NULL.

Will my virtual functions be able to once again go into the private scope when I create derived classes or must they be public?

I want to avoid them being public due to my design.
Thanks

Comment: You can make a virtual function private if you like. Also, this seems like a needlessly complicated design. What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: well, its because I want event handlers hence the function pointers, the user will be able to set callbacks through an addHandler function

Comment: @JoshD The idea is for example:
Regular non-overridable paint calls virtual paint and then calls the event handler of the user (the function pointer(if it is set))

Comment: @Milo: I'm confused about why you have a non-overrideable function call a virtual function rather than directly calling the virtual function. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @JoshD because the pattern will always be:
the overridden function, then try to call the event handler. I do not want developers to be allowed to change this so that the event handler is not called.

Comment: @Milo, i agree with others, you should define an interface that the widget implements and just call those functions directly, let c++ do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @pm100 How does this guarantee that for example, when a paint event occurs, that both the paint event, and the paint event handler function pointer are called?

Comment: @JoshD: it's called the Template Method pattern, and specifically in C++ the Non-Virtual Interface idiom is an almost-trivial use of it. If you want to read more about the benefits of those two things, you now have the search terms ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Thanks! It's intriguing, and I'm glad you gave me the means to learn more.

Comment: @Milo: Yes. I would call it nearly a standard design technique. i.e. A pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Virtual functions can have `public`, `protected`, or `private` access.

A discussion of them via the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/index.html).

- [Should I use protected virtuals instead of public virtuals?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.3)
- [When should someone use private virtuals?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.4)

Answer (score 2):

They can be private and do not need to be public.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they can't be private, because then nothing can override them.

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps surprisingly they can be overridden even if they are private. (For more discussion of the details of virtual functions also see here: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm)

Comment: @Daniel T.: You can still override a private virtual method in a derived class.  What you can't do is call the base class version.

Comment: Whoops, just noticed that this was tagged C++. I was referring to C#. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Though they can be public, it is not considered as good design principle as [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) says.

Answer (score 1):

virtual functions can be `private`. This is because `private`  means that the function cannot be called by derived classes. It does not prevent the entry to the v-table being overwritten. This means that the both the base class and the derived class will have access to the overwritten virtual function.